# How do I find resistors values for a TTL to ECL interface?

Tags: resistors, voltage-divider, logic-gates, interface, component-values

[image]

This is the photo of the ttl to ecl interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with TTL logic high and low output voltage levels, and the desired logic high and low voltage levels for the ECL input.  With these values and Ohm's Law, you can calculate the three resistor values by assigning an arbitrary value to one of them and calculating the other two.

That is a starting point.  Next, you have to determine the ECL input current for each logic state, and adjust the resistor values accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using one of the many ECL to TTL translators such as the MC10ELT25. The data sheet can be found here. https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/104765.pdf